Types of relations- Reflexive, Symmetric, Transitive, Identity, Universal, Null and Equivalence relations
By the definition of it, it appears that a relation can be an identity relation or a reflexive relation only if the relation is on a single set (ie. it is subset of cartesian product of a set with itself) while a relation can be transitive, null, universal or symmetric irrespective  of whether the relation on a single set or is between 2, 3 or more sets (ie. its a subset of cartesian product of 2, 3 or more sets respectively)
is my analogy correct ?
can a relation between 2 sets be an identity or a reflexive relation ?
Please explain.
As far as I know,
Identity relation on, say, set A is {(a,a): for every a belonging to A}
A relation on, say, set A is Reflexive if (a,a) for every a belonging to A is a member of the relation
A relation (say R) on, say, set A is Symmetric if there exists (b,a) in R for every (a,b) belonging to R
A relation (say R) on, say, set A is Transitive if there exists (a,c) in R for every (a,b) and (b,c) belonging to R
Null relation is { } since its a subset of every cartesian product
Universal relation is the cartesian product itself since every set is a subset of itself
